# Do we need to add the sign before the unknown value in the mirror formula?

Tags: optics, reflection, conventions, lenses

I was doing a problem in Optics and I had to use the mirror formula for one specific step i.e 1/u + 1/v = 1/f.

Okay so it's a concave mirror, with the object placed behind the focus. That means V, U and f are all going to be negative(sign convention). Now I know the value of U and f , and the value of V is supposed to be found. Should I substitute V as (-V) or keep it as V itself? I'm not sure if the answer would come with the correct sign.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep confusion with conventions and signs in geometric optics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240743/)

Answer (score 0):

The variables u,v,and f here can take any +ve or -ve values. If you add a minus sign to it, you are changing its value and therefore get the answer for a different situation.

So, don't use the negative sign with a variable.